# Is it efficient to use nested hashtables for this practice problem?

Tags: algorithm, performance, data-structures, hashmap, hashtable

I've been tasked with finding the most efficient solution to the following problem: I need to print out the (k) most streamed movies of genre, (g), in the given year, (y),  i can assume it takes o(1) to retrieve the current year. An example of this is:
Every time a movie is streamed, i'm given the name of the movie and the genre. 
 "What are the top **5** most streamed **romance** movies in the year **2014**?

The returned answer might be something like

- MovieName1 (romance)  3409 streams
- MovieName2 (romance)  4000 streams
- MovieName3 (romance)  5340 streams
- MovieName4 (romance)  9000 streams
- MovieName5 (romance)  10000 streams

So my thought process is to use 3 nested hashtables.

- One where i use they name (key) to map to the frequency (value)
- One where i use the genre(key) to map to a map(name,frequency)(value)
- And the final one where i use the year(key) to map to a map(genre,
  map(name, frequency) (value)

Does that make any sense...I think confused myself just by writing this..
Is it possible to just use a single hashtable that uses they year as a key and maps to a linked list of nodes where every single node contains the movie name, frequency, and genre? Would this be more efficient?

So if i wanted to update batmans frequency i can just do map.get(2008) which would give the head of the linked list
and then do
 `while(tmp != null){
    if(tmp.name == "the dark knight"){
    temp.frequency++;
    }`

Comment: Is this an assignment or an actual real-life problem you need to solve? In other words, do you really want the single most efficient solution, or do you want the best one overall? And if it's an assignment, is it about time complexity or practical performance?

Comment: just a practice problem, im studying for an exam. This is a question a professor assigned to previous years. Looking for time complexity of most efficient solution using any data structure

Comment: Is it always going to be top X movies? Can you get asked the same question without the year / or without the category (like top 10 movies of 2014, or top romance movies of all times?)

Comment: Do you mean the solution with best time-complexity, or the most performant solution along with its time complexity (which might not be the same)? I'm guessing it's the former. Also, what do you mean by "i can assume it takes o(1) to retrieve the current year"?

Comment: Can a movie classified as both romance and comedy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you thought about using a hashmap of years to hashmaps of genres to hashmaps of names to frequencies. Does it make sense? Sure. Is it a good way to solve your problem? Most likely not. It is also possible, as you say, to use a single main hashmap of years to collections of genre-name-frequency tuples (or structures, in a lot of languages - like C, C++, Java, and so on). By collections, you thought of linked lists, but you could very well use vectors or something else (linked lists are very often the worst kind of data structures). But this would not be more efficient and is not necessarily a better way to solve your problem, even though it may be more readable and maintainable.

I won't be talking about performance improvements that don't impact time complexity, since you've made it clear in the comments that it's for an exam that only cares about time complexity (which is sad, but whatever). Also, I'm assuming this is the only problem you need to solve.

Let's see how to improve your ideas. It just so happens that a mix of both your solutions, along with one improvement, gives the best possible solution in terms of time complexity, that is `O(k)`. First, note that each movie name is associated with only one frequency, and each frequency is associated with (likely) only one movie name. And since you want to retrieve movie names based on frequencies, a hashmap has no advantage over a linear collection of name-frequency pairs, such as a vector or a linked list. Then, note that each year and each genre is (independently) associated with multiple movies (each with both a name and a frequency). So a hashmap has a place here: with a given year and a given genre, a hashmap-like structure would give you the relevent movies in expected constant time.

Combine these two results and you get a hashmap with years and genres as keys and collections of name-frequency pairs as values. The one improvement that makes it possible to retrieve the `k` most streamed movies for given year and genre in `O(k)` time complexity is a sort: if your name-frequency pairs are sorted by frequency in every collection, you can simply return the first (or last, depending on the order) `k` names.

One detail that you may find weird is that the hashmap uses both years and genres as keys. That's an implementation detail. You can do it by using two nested hashmaps, one using years as keys and the other using genres, or you can combine years and genres and directly use these pairs as keys. It's actually straightforward to hash year-genre pairs.

Comment: wow...you made it so understandable..can't thank you enough!!

Comment: @Dezque Well you can always mark the answer as *accepted*. Also, remember that time complexity is only part of performance. Even if the exam is only about time complexity.

Comment: Right on!! tyvm